# React Native Navigation Error:the component for the route must be a React Component

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Hello Every one I am new to react native I am building a very simple navigation system but i am getting this error.Please any one guide me 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHgP.jpg%60)
The screenshot attached above is the error i am running on my physical android phone S7 edge Oreo 8.0

```html
***Homescreen.js***
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return <Text style={styles.text}>Hello World</Text>;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});
```

```html
***App.js***
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen'
import ComponentsScreen from './src/screens/ComponentsScreen'

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Components:ComponentsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Components',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "App"
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

```html
***ComponentsScreen.js***
import React from 'react'
import {Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

const ComponentsScreen=function(){
    return <Text style={styles.textStyle}>This is the Components Screen</Text>
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    textStyle:{
    fontSize:30
    }
})
```

Comment: you forgot to export default the component inside `HomeScreen.js`

`export default HomeScreen`

Comment: Sorry,it did not have any effect the error is still there

Comment: And what about export of componentScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried you code its working perfectly just add exports in your HomeScreen and ComponentsScreen:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return <Text style={styles.text}>Hello World</Text>;
};

export default HomeScreen;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});
```

ComponentsScreen:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

const ComponentsScreen=function(){
    return <Text style={styles.textStyle}>This is the Components Screen</Text>
}

export default ComponentsScreen;
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    textStyle:{
    fontSize:30
    }
})
```

And make sure you have correct name declaration you had declared Homescreen component as Homescreen, where s is small but you are importing in your App.js with caps, check this.

Hope this helps!